# java array name length issues

Tags: java, arrays, methods

i cant necessarily figure out how to use a loop to create my array elements and print. my homework wants me to Create a new array of int called nameLengths. Write a loop to iterate over the previously created names array and add the length of each name to the nameLengths array.

ive googled around and looked at a lot of other peoples similar questions and cant quite figure out exactly how to implement it to my specific code.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class arrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] ages = new int[9];
        //array of ages
        ages[0] = 3;
        ages[1] = 9;
        ages[2] = 23;
        ages[3] = 64;
        ages[4] = 2;
        ages[5] = 8;
        ages[6] = 28;
        ages[7] = 93;
        ages[8] = 22;
        // average age print
        System.out.println(average(ages));
        //subtraction code
            int i = ages[ages.length - 1] - ages[0];
            System.out.println("age difference:");
            System.out.println(i);

           String[] names = new String[6];{
                names[0] = "Sam";
                names[1] = "Tommy";
                names[2] = "Tim";
                names[3] = "Sally";
                names[4] = "Buck";
                names[5] = "Bob";
                }
        int[] nameLengths = new int[names.length - 1];  {

            }   
            System.out.println("average number of characers per name");
            System.out.println(averageNumberOfChar(names));
            System.out.println("concatination");
            System.out.println(createConcatination(names));
            System.out.println(findNameLength(names));
            }



            public static int sum(int[] numbers , String String) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int number : numbers) {
                    sum += number;
                }
            return sum;
            }
            public static int average(int[] numbers) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int number : numbers) {
                    sum += number;
                }
                System.out.println("average age:");
            return sum / numbers.length;
       }
            public static int averageNumberOfChar(String[] names) {
                int total=0;
                for (int j = 0; j < names.length; j++) {
                    total += names[j].length();

                }
                return total / names.length;
            }
            public static String createConcatination(String[] names) {
                int k = 0;
                String concatination = names[k];
                for(k = 0; k < names.length; k++) {
                    System.out.print(names[k] + " ");
                }
                return concatination;
            }
            public static int findNameLength(int[] names){
                int length = 0;
                for(int l = 0; l < names.length; l ++) {
                System.out.println(names[l]);
            }
                return length;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `Stream<String>` from the `names` array using `Arrays.stream()` and map it to an `IntStream` of string lengths by using `String::length` mapping function and collect the resulting `IntStream` into an array of int representing the length of the names:

```
String[] names = {
            "Sam",
            "Tommy",
            "Tim",
            "Sally",
            "Buck",
            "Bob"
        };
int[] nameLengths = Arrays.stream(names)
                          .mapToInt(String::length)
                          .toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nameLengths));
```

Output:

```
[3, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3]
```

Or if you want to use a traditional for-loop:

```
 int[] nameLengths = new int[names.length];
 for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
     nameLengths[i] = names[i].length();
 }
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nameLengths));
```